# Get tag from HTML element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a search box with two tabs to choose which type to search. I want to add .active class to list item whose search_type equals to a params from a request (i.e., params[request_type]).

```
<ul data-tabs="tabs" class="tabs">
  <li search_type="Things">
     <a href="#Things">Things</a>
  </li>
  <li search_type="People">
    <a href="#People">People</a>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

I tried to compare in jQuery:

```
$('.tabs .li).(function(){  
if($(this).search_type == myParams){
   $(this).addClass('.active');
  }
});
```

However, my $(this).search_type turns out to be undefined, even though in web-browser, the element shows up correctly as:

```
<li search_type="Things"> 
  <a href="#Things">Things</a>
</li>
```

My question is: how to I get search_type from li?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.tabs .li').(function(){  
if($(this).attr('search_type') == myParams){
   $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Notice the `$(this).attr()` and also, in `addClass` dont put `.` ... only the class name.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `$(this).attr('search_type')`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference `search_type` directly, try `$(this).attr('search_type')` and see what happened